# Is it possible to enter Hungary from Serbia?

Tags: visas, paperwork, hungary, tunisian-citizens

I am a non-EU citizen trying to enter Hungary from Serbia by train or bus.

I have a visa type D single entry for Hungary.

My travel plan: From Tunisia to Belgrade, Serbia and then from Belgrade to Budapest.

Will I face any kinds of problems?

Comment: Not saying it can't happen, but a _single-entry_ type D visa sounds really strange. Are you sure that is what you have?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah i'm sure

Comment: @HenningMakholm Means OP, once in Schengen, must not leave until they get their residence permit

Comment: @HenningMakholm thank you that's what i needed to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can; the Serbian-Hungarian crossings used by buses and trains are open to all.

Once you're in the Schengen Area, don't leave until you get your residence permit card.